# Google Drive API search for folder in Team Drive folder with many folder levels; if exists return ID if not create folder at the correct level

Tags: google-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to locate a folder inside a Google Team Drive, which has a folder structure with multiple levels.

Here is an example:

```
Team Drive

    - Folder A

       - Folder B

           - Folder C
```

I would like to search for `Folder C` by using the folder ID of the Team Drive.  If the folder exists, return the folder ID for `Folder C` and if not, create that folder under `Folder B`.

So, I have some code I am working with, creating the Google Drive API query.

Here is the code snippet I am using - (Team Drive ID) would be the ID:

```
// Set the drive query...
String driveQuery = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '(Team Drive ID)' in parents and name='Folder C' and trashed=false";

try {
    result = service.files().list().setQ(driveQuery).setIncludeTeamDriveItems(true).setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
            .execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (File folder : result.getFiles()) {
    System.out.printf("Found folder: %s (%s)\n", folder.getName(), folder.getId());
    foundFolder = true;
    folderID = folder.getId();
}
if (foundFolder != true) {
    // Need to create the folder...
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName(folderKeyToGet);
    fileMetadata.setTeamDriveId(parentFolderID);
    fileMetadata.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(parentFolderID));

    try {
        newFolder = service.files().create(fileMetadata).setSupportsTeamDrives(true).setFields("id, parents")
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Send back the folder ID...
    folderID = newFolder.getId();
    System.out.println("Folder ID: " + newFolder.getId());
}

return folderID;
```

I have the query set to:

```
"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '(Team Drive ID)' in parents and name='Folder C' and trashed=false"
```

but is seems not to traverse the folder structure to find the `Folder C` folder.

Do I need to have the `Folder B` folder ID to find the folder or is there a way to have the query search the whole Team Drive for the folder?

Comment: As per my understanding I don't think there is any ready made API/option available to search through Sub folders. You need to traverse through Folder B in order to get to Folder C. Use recursion, there are examples available for this kind of traversal.